# AngularJS JSON load from file with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-click, ng-view, ng-controller

Currently I want to show HTML table by parsing JSON data from file using Angular JS, And It's not working can someone please help me?

And Also As a Enhancement How Can I get the 2 Divs for 2 different JSON file

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
    <div ng-controller="get_controller">
        <input type="text" ng-model="accountnumber" name="accountnumber" class="form-control search-query" placeholder="Enter Account Number">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" ng-click="geValues()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="get_controller">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-repeat="list in personDetails">{{list.Name}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="features" ng-repeat="list in personDetails">{{list.Location}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</html>
```

**Angular JS Code**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngTable"]);
app.controller('get_controller', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.geValues =  function() {
        $http({method: 'POST', url: 'posts.json'}).success(function(data) {
            $scope.post = data;
            $scope.personDetails = Employee;
             })
    },
});
```

**posts.json (Json File)**

```
{
  "Employee": [
    {
      "Name": "Rocky",
      "Location": "Office"
    },
    {
      "Name": "John",
      "Location": "Home"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: whats the error? what is Employee? it should be `data. Employee`.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg
Sorry I have this code in the but i missed to add Employee= data['Employee'];
 
Issue is When I click on button I am able to get the data in Console but I am not seeing table populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be a GET request, also the you need to access the data from the response object which contains the Employee array. Code should be,

```
$http.get('test.json').then(function (response){
  $scope.post = response.data;
  $scope.personDetails = response.data.Employee;
});
```

if you want it to happen on ng-click, put the call inside a function,

```
  $scope.geValues = function() {
      $http.get('test.json').then(function(response) {
        $scope.post = response.data;
        $scope.personDetails = response.data.Employee;

      });
    }
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/FYIzkZXS9gFlcK6tv3RC?p=preview)

Comment: @MaheshGadagi Check now

Comment: Really Thanks , I am able to get the data table  But I want to be done after clicking the button. Can you please help me in that

Comment: I will really upvote this once I am eligible Thanks @Sajeetharan